# How to use frame animation with MediaPlayer?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-mediaplayer

Frame animation interrupts music in `MediaPlayer`. How to avoid it? I can't use `SoundPool`, because my audio file is long.

Code

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(FirstScreen.this, R.raw.main_munu);
mediaPlayer.start();

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mainMenuImageView.setImageDrawable(null);
            mainMenuImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.despair_logo_animation);
        }
    }, 6000);
```